# M is a Turing machine that accepts string w and does not accept string ε

Tags: theory, turing-machines, computation

I need to prove whether this language is recognizable or not:

> { ⟨M, w⟩: M is a Turing machine that accepts string w and does not accept string ε }

I figure I could do a reduction on A<sub>TM</sub>, but how do I handle the empty string?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you would find a better fit for this question on [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hint: this language is not recognizable.

Comment: Thanks! This should mean that there is a function that maps the complement of Atm to my language.I could assume a recognizer for ~Atm and output the opposite but that still does not take care of the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do a reduction from the complement of A<sub>TM</sub> to your language.

Given a TM M and a string w, build this TM/string pair:

```
M' = "On input x:
         If x = "iheartquokkas", accept.
         Otherwise:
            Run M on w.
            If M accepts, accept;
            If M rejects, reject;
            (Implicitly: if M loops, loop.)"
w' = "iheartquokkas"
```

First, suppose that M does not accept w. Then machine M' does indeed accept the string w', because it's programmed to do so. Additionally, when you run M' on ε, it will run M on w and never accept because M doesn't accept w. Thus M' accepts w' but not ε, so ⟨M', w'⟩ is in your language.

Second, suppose that M accepts w. Then when you run M' on ε, it will accept, so it is not the case that M' accepts w' but not ε. Therefore, ⟨M', w'⟩ is not in your language.

You now have a mapping reduction from A<sub>TM</sub>'s complement to your language, so your language isn't recognizable.

Now, can you prove that it's not co-recognizable?